# How to resize web page to make room for a Chrome extension toolbar

Tags: html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that will show a toolbar at the bottom of every page and shrink the tab content to the rest of the browser tab height.

Currently, I'm using a content script to serve an iframe where I want it with position = 'fixed' so that it will stay there rather than scrolling, and a high z-value so that it's always on top.

PROBLEM: I'm having issues with resizing the rest of the webpage, however, and portions of it are sitting behind the toolbar. I tried adding the appropriate amount of padding to the  but it doesn't resize many pages properly that are designed to fill the screen e.g. facebook.com/messages.

Ideally, it should work exactly how the Chrome browser's own downloads shelf at the bottom of the screen behaves.

Any ideas?

Note: I don't want to use a separate window, as this extension does. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tidy-sidebar/dgmacifhhpefamjmolpipkijcofcmbgp?hl=en

Note 2: Bonus for anyone who knows a way of achieving this as well as avoiding the use of an iframe. (iframes won't be served on any page with a decent Content Security Policy e.g. github.com, linkedin.com)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a bottom margin on the parent html for the current page that is equal to the height of your app container. Elements that are fixed, etc... to the bottom of the page will have to be queried by their computed style and offset with the same amount of height, and then reset once the container is hidden again.

here is a fiddle, minus the fixed elements offset: https://jsfiddle.net/oqL56h5q/3/

```
<button id='open-app'>open app</button>
<button id='close-app'>close app</button>

body {
  background-color: red;
}

#appcontainer {
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1000001;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

var APPCONTAINER_HEIGHT = '160px';
var CONTAINER_ID = 'appcontainer';

var html = document.querySelector('html');

var appView = {
    appContainer: null,

    init: function() {
      this.appContainer = document.createElement('DIV');
      this.appContainer.id = CONTAINER_ID;
      this.appContainer.style.height = APPCONTAINER_HEIGHT;
      return appView;
    },

  render: function() {
    html.appendChild(this.appContainer);
    html.marginBottom = APPCONTAINER_HEIGHT;
    return appView;
  },

  hide: function() {
    this.appContainer.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.querySelector('#open-app').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    appView.init();
    return appView.render();
});

document.querySelector('#close-app').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (appView.appContainer) {
    html.marginBottom = '0px';
    return appView.hide();
  }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is actually similar to the solution that I already have, which involves adding say 100px margin or padding to the body (which technically keeps the content the same length and adds 100px to the bottom, which makes the page 100px longer). 
This doesn't work for pages such as https://www.facebook.com/messages/ that are single page apps that are designed to take up the entire page and don't allow you to scroll. 
Is there a way to actually trick the web page into thinking the viewport is 100px shorter than it actually is, such that SPAs are sized properly?